Cannot use pac4j with jetty 12.0.8
I cannot use pac4j 6.1.0 or any other version with jetty 12 newer than 12.0.8.
See for more informations this issue:
https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/12518
Can anybody help?
Thanks!

Sure. Let's continue the discussion on the Github issue
